# Is there anyway to view what keywords a user used to find an iOS or Android App?

Tags: app-store-connect, analytics, google-developers-console

Is there anyway to export a report from iTunesConnect or the Google Developer Console to determine which keywords were used to find your application?

Comment: Not possible for iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various tools ( some of them are paid )

Google Keyword Planner - [link](https://adwords.google.com/intl/en_in/home/tools/keyword-planner/)

ios Search Ads - [link](https://searchads.apple.com/)

App Annie Keyword Tool - [link](https://www.appannie.com/intelligence/marketing/aso/ios/keyword-top)

Google Adword Campaigns - [link](https://adwords.google.com/home/)